# WebClipIcon Not Being Displayed for iOS Web App When Add To Home Screen Selected

Tags: web-applications, ios4

I have a web app that I wrote for mobile Safari, and added the following line to enable a custom WebClipIcon :

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="YES">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="startup.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="Images/WebClipIcon.png">
```

I replaced the original WebClipIcon.png with a new one, in the same location. So, I figured this should work. But, when the app is open, and I select Add to Home Screen, all I get is the icon that has a preview of the page I'm on. I've looked through the Dashcode documentation, and it seems this should work. Anybody have any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

I have deleted and tried adding the app to my home screen multiple times, so I don't think caching is the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your apple-touch-icon has to be in the root folder.... at least that's how I understand it (you shouldn't even have to reference it if it is). Also - "apple-touch-icon.png" should be the file name, not WebClipIcon.png. Can't deny that I have limited knowledge on this tho.